# why are there multiple layers of caches

Tags: caching

Does anyone know why in most of todays processors there are several layers of caches. Like L1 L2 and L3. Why cant a processor do with one big L1 cache?

Isnt having multiple layers of cache increases the complexity of caching protocols?

Comment: OT. But the simple answer is, we can't build something as *fast* as the `L1` cache, with the *size* of the `L3` cache. Or to put it another way, if we could achieve all of the size/speed tradeoffs in our favour, we wouldn't need cache at all - the main memory would be as fast as the `L1` cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die size. L1 is usually on-die; there is not room for a large cache on-die. L2/3 gets its own die and can be bigger and processed differently.

Also speed; L1 is built with tradeoffs for maximum speed, while L2/3 doesn't have to be as aggressively sped up.

Also multi-core. Modern multi-core processors give each core its own L1 for speed, but they share some or all of the other caches for coherency.

That said, PA-RISC processors *have* been built with the "let's just make a big L1 cache" approach. They were expensive.

Answer (score 3):

> Why cant a processor do with one big L1 cache?

The larger your processor cache, the longer the latency. There are also practical and cost considerations, since larger caches occupy more physical space on a chip. After a certain size, you lose too much of the caching speedup to make it worth it to increase cache size further. Eventually, therefore, a large cache becomes undesirable.

Processor designs that still want a large cache can make a tradeoff by having multiple cache levels. You start with a small and fast cache, and gradually fall back to larger, slower caches on successive misses.

Answer (score 0):

B/c in today's architectures you have more than one CPU/core accessing the memory. The L3 cache is a cache of caches that is shared between all the CPUs. This reduces the amount of data that needs to go through the memory bus, which is usually a good idea. If you want, you can have a look at : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz9Og.jpg which shows how the layers are organized and how did they evolve through time.